# I tried to open a csv file but instead of loading the csv file, it printed its html document

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/diazonic/Machine-Learning-using-sklearn/blob/master/Datasets/news.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Use 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diazonic/Machine-Learning-using-sklearn/master/Datasets/news.csv'

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/diazonic/Machine-Learning-using-sklearn/blob/master/Datasets/news.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

By:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diazonic/Machine-Learning-using-sklearn/master/Datasets/news.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When reading data from github, you need to pass in the raw version of the data in read.csv(), you are using the display version. You can get the URL for the raw version by clicking on the Raw button displayed above the data.

The display version is actually an html file that wraps the actual csv to make it better looking.

You can access the raw version by clicking the RAW button on top-right of the file in github.

[image]

Copy the url to this page. This is the actual CSV.

Replace:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://github.com/diazonic/Machine-Learning-using-sklearn/blob/master/Datasets/news.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```

With :

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/diazonic/Machine-Learning-using-sklearn/master/Datasets/news.csv', error_bad_lines=False)
```